# Algolia search/Symfony :Too few arguments to function

Tags: symfony, search, algolia

When trying to do a simple search method with Algolia. The search method will query Algolia to get matching results and then will create a doctrine collection. I get this error:

[image: Too few arguments to function]

I injected my indexManager in my controller :

```
class ProductController extends Controller
{
    protected $indexManager;

    public function __construct(IndexManagerInterface $indexingManager)
    {
        $this->indexManager = $indexingManager;
    }

    public function displayAction(Request $request) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManagerForClass(Product::class);

        $posts = $this->indexManager->search('query', Product::class, $em);

        return $this->render('ProductBundle:Default:postDisplay.html.twig', array(
                'posts' => $posts));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you make sure the `autowire` feature is set to `true`?
https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html

Symfony should resolve the dependency automatically.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I followed the documentation but in vain.I don't really understand the utility of (Autowiring) in my case.Need more details about it..